# How to read plot points from a text file, reading each line of text individually?

Tags: python, file, turtle-graphics

So I am very new to coding, and I have to draw an image in python using multiple separate polygons with turtle with the plot points all contained in a single .txt file. I have my file set up, so each set of points is on a different line of text, but I'm just not sure how to call each line of text individually to the program.
Like this:

```
-30,9,108,5,110,16,33,72,-42,75,-30,9
-171,15,-56,10,-64,78,-161,77,-171,15
-201,17,-182,75,-322,75,-340,18,-201,17
-378,-32,-366,-31,-361,17,-335,84,-345,84,-372,18,-378,-32
366,-24,355,-27,355,-45,372,-45,366,-24
-149,-2,-187,0,-187,-7,-150,-6,-149,-2
-1,-8,-37,-4,-37,-10,-2,-11,-1,-8
```

Here is the code that I have so far, not including the code that involves actually drawing the image:

```py
import turtle
import os
import re

file_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

movements = ""

with open(file_directory + '\\plotpoints.txt', "r") as plotme:
    movements = movements + plotme.readlines()

plotme.close()

pointlist = movements.split(",")

for counter in range(0, len(pointlist)):
    pointlist[counter] = int(pointlist[counter])
```

Like I said, I'm very new to coding, so anything at all to help me understand this better would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `plotme.close()`. The `with` context takes care of that already. Also, try to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os`. It will make your life easier.

Comment: Your coding is importing `re` and `turtle`, but they are not being used in the snippet you posted. Where is your attempt to plot the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was good, but to achieve the result you need to do this:

1. remove `plotme.close()` as this is handled by the `with` block (context manager).
2. use `os.path.join()` if you are joining paths.
3. `for loop` inside the `with` block to read all lines to a list.

```py
import os

file_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
full_path = os.path.join(file_directory,'plotpoints.txt')

movements = []

with open(full_path, "r") as plotme:
    for line in plotme.readlines():
        movements.extend(line.strip().split(","))
    
# convert strings to ints
movements = [int(x) for x in movements]

print(movements)
```

result:

```
[-30, 9, 108, 5, 110, 16, 33, 72, -42, 75, -30, 9, -171, 15, -56, 10, -64, 78, -161, 77, -171, 15, -201, 17, -182, 75, -322, 75, -340, 18, -201, 17, -378, -32, -366, -31, -361, 17, -335, 84, -345, 84, -372, 18, -378, -32, 366, -24, 355, -27, 355, -45, 372, -45, 366, -24, -149, -2, -187, 0, -187, -7, -150, -6, -149, -2, -1, -8, -37, -4, -37, -10, -2, -11, -1, -8]
```

you can then use this result for plotting...

Here is an alternative option for producing a list of lists for each shape:

```py
import os

file_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
full_path = os.path.join(file_directory,'plotpoints.txt')

movements = []

with open(full_path, "r") as plotme:
    for line in plotme.readlines():
        shape = line.strip().split(",")
        shape = [int(x) for x in shape]
        movements.append(shape)

print(movements)
```

An the result looks like this:

```
[[-30, 9, 108, 5, 110, 16, 33, 72, -42, 75, -30, 9],
 [-171, 15, -56, 10, -64, 78, -161, 77, -171, 15],
 [-201, 17, -182, 75, -322, 75, -340, 18, -201, 17],
 [-378, -32, -366, -31, -361, 17, -335, 84, -345, 84, -372, 18, -378, -32],
 [366, -24, 355, -27, 355, -45, 372, -45, 366, -24],
 [-149, -2, -187, 0, -187, -7, -150, -6, -149, -2],
 [-1, -8, -37, -4, -37, -10, -2, -11, -1, -8]]
```